# python: machine learning mastery: time data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/) tutorial and I got stuck right at the beginning. I have downloaded the dataset from [here](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22r0/sales-of-shampoo-over-a-three-year-period#!ds=22r0&display=line) by clicking to "Export" and then "CSV (,)".

When using the following snippet of code proposed in the tutorial

```
# load and plot dataset
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load dataset
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')
series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
# summarize first few rows
print(series.head())
# line plot
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
time data '190Sales of shampoo over a three year period' does not match format '%Y-%m'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `shampoo-sales.csv` is the (unexpected) row

> `Sales of shampoo over a three year period`

Your `parser()` is trying put `190` in front of it:

> `190Sales of shampoo over a three year period`

and then convert it by provided pattern `'%Y-%m'`, so you obtained the mentioned error.

Just *delete that row* from `shampoo-sales.csv` (don't forget to save it) and your program will run.

Comment: I did it and now I still get an error: `time data '19001-Jan' does not match format '%Y-%m'`

Comment: While editing your downloaded `CSV` file (to remove that long text near end of the file) you have to change the first data row (so you obtained `"01-Jan",266.0` instead of `"1-01",266.0`.  Maybe other rows, too. Just download that `CSV` file again, remove the long text near end of file, save it (and rename it to conform your file name in your code). I tried it (again) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to look at the CSV file, I'd guess that the first row and first column is 'Sales of shampoo over a three year period'
Take a look at what `head()` is returning.  I bet there is a header row in there.